# how to run apps on emulator without errors

Tags: android, android-emulator

The emulator loads and shows the message as "Unfortunately app has stopped"
PLS help me.... and this is shown in the console

```
[2012-09-16 23:32:25 - Demo] Android Launch!
[2012-09-16 23:32:25 - Demo] adb is running normally.
[2012-09-16 23:32:25 - Demo] Performing com.example.demo.MainActivity2 activity launch
[2012-09-16 23:32:25 - Demo] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Emulator1'
[2012-09-16 23:32:25 - Demo] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Emulator1'
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
[2012-09-16 23:32:31 - Emulator] 
[2012-09-16 23:32:32 - Demo] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-09-16 23:32:32 - Demo] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-09-16 23:33:36 - Demo] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-09-16 23:33:36 - Demo] Uploading Demo.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-09-16 23:33:36 - Demo] Installing Demo.apk...
[2012-09-16 23:34:36 - Demo] Success!
[2012-09-16 23:34:36 - Demo] Starting activity com.example.demo.MainActivity2 on device emulator-5554
[2012-09-16 23:34:38 - Demo] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.demo/.MainActivity2 }
[2012-09-16 23:41:22 - Demo] ------------------------------
```

Comment: you should post code and the logcat error

Comment: As far as I can see, your emulator works just fine the problem is with your app. please post your logcat output.

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in initialization, hence a fresh installation is recommended. It could also be a problem with the apk package though, yet freshly install the emulator and try the same, if it still doesn't work then its a problem with the package and not the emulator, but i think its because of a missing file or config, anyway try this out and hopefully it should work, else the package is broken or corrupt.

Uninstall the program completely.

Then follow these videos and you will be good to go :

Installing Emulator correctly -
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwnPpVpzJSk&feature=youtube_gdata_player

Get apps on android emulator -
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=979dyHuZG9I&feature=youtube_gdata_player

The games or apps won't run as fast as it would on an actual android device though.

All the best. Hope i helped.